# Java Fx undo functionality in a board game with 3D components

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am making a chess game in javafx. Can I use stages in javafx to save the state of the board and on exiting and clicking resume, show the board in the same state as before? 
I do not want to use serialising.

Comment: Try `java.util.prefs.Preferences`.

Comment: "Can I use stages in javafx to save the state of the board". What do you mean by "stages" in this context? Surely all you need to do is save the list of moves up to that point (and time left on the players' clocks, if you are implementing a game clock).